# Markdown reference to a code/output cell in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: markdown, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have executed some code snippet:

```
In  [16]: print "hello"
Out [16]: hello
```

Is there a way to refer to that in/out cell in my markdown text, like:

```
See the results in $ACell
```

where `$ACell` evaluates to 16 (in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been requested and discussed before, but isn't currently supported.

Links to tracking issues:

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2958
- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1098